# How to add or attach "click" event listener in DOM?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, mobile-webkit

Am not able to add events to a id. Though **able to attach event** listener onLoad but same **not working** for onClick or click. Can somebody help me to fix it?

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd"><html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" id="iphone-viewport" content="minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, width=device-width">
    <title>Astro Wheel</title>
<script type="text/javascript">

function loaded() {
alert("Loaded")
var ele= document.getElementById("aries");
if (window.attachEvent) 
{ ele.attachEvent('click', testFunction); }
else if (window.addEventListener)
 { ele.addEventListener('click', testFunction, true); }
 // I am unable to register a event on #aries, below alerts giving "null" and "undefined" respectively
 alert(ele.onclick);
 alert(ele.click)

}

function testFunction(){
alert("Clicked")
}
window.addEventListener("load", function() { setTimeout(loaded, 100); }, true);
</script>
<style type="text/css">
body, ul, li, div, p { padding:0; margin:0; }
body { background:#444 url(bg.png); }
#wheel { position:absolute; z-index:1; width:320px; height:321px; overflow:hidden; }
#display1 { position:absolute; z-index:100; width:320px; height:321px;  }
ul { position:absolute; z-index:10; width:320px; height:320px;
    -webkit-transform-origin:50% 50%;
    -webkit-transform:rotateZ(0rad);
    text-align:center;
}
ul li { position:absolute; z-index:11; width:76px; height:88px; left:122px; top:22px; overflow:hidden;
    -webkit-transform-origin:38px 138px;
    -webkit-transition-timing-function:ease-out;
    -webkit-transition-duration:800ms;
}
#aries {-webkit-transform:rotate(0deg) translate(0, -0px); }
#cancer {-webkit-transform:rotate(90deg) translate(0, -000px); }
#libra {-webkit-transform:rotate(180deg) translate(0, -0000px); }
#caprico { -webkit-transform:rotate(270deg) translate(0, -000px); }

</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="wheel">
    <div id="display1"></div>
    <ul id="zodiac">
        <li id="aries"><div>Aries</div></li>
        <li id="cancer"><div>Cancer</div></li>
        <li id="libra"><div>Libra</div></li>
        <li id="caprico"><div>Caprico</div></li>
    </ul>
    <div id="ok"></div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

P.S. I am not allowed to use any framework.**Testing** on WEBKIT based mobile browser and Google Chrome only

Comment: I feel this should be posted on Stack Overflow. Code Review is for reviewing working code.

Comment: If your question is "How do I..." then what you're asking for is **not** a review. This belongs on Stack Overflow.

Comment: Can any body please tell me as where am going wrong. I have updated testings info.

Comment: To be honest I'm not sure.  If I put the click handler on "display1" it works, but not on the `<li>` tags.

Comment: ok, it looks like something in your CSS (z-orders?) is preventing click events from eaching your `<li>` tags.

Comment: @Alnitak: http://jsfiddle.net/kNnVH/21/ Here is one test. I guess its working without css that include webkit attributes. Can webkit attributes be a problem??

Comment: it's your `#display1` class - it has a high zorder so overlays the other divs, preventing them from being clicked.

Comment: @Alnitak: Correct. Solved.Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Using `addEventListener` (or IE's `attachEvent`) doesn't change the contents of the `onclick` attribute - they're independent.
2. There shouldn't be any need to time delay the `loaded()` function - just do:

   `window.addEventListener('load', loaded, false);`
3. If you're assuming W3C DOM event handling (which your `load` handler does) then there's no need for the IE-ony `attachEvent()` call

Comment: can you please help me in figuring out as where am going wrong?