# Dynamic iFrame resize on radio click

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe, dynamic, resize

I have a page with an iframe that should resize dynamically when the user chooses any option from a radio list.

I've found some solutions for dynamically resizing the parent window for an iframe, but I haven't found out how to bind that event to a radio button on a form with no submit button.

Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: you could call a method on selection of a radio button and inside that method, do the resizing

Comment: You might want to check into [`addEventListener`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget.addEventListener) and the like. This will allow you attach a listener to the radio input. Take it from there!

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to add or attach "click" event listener in DOM?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5369319/how-to-add-or-attach-click-event-listener-in-dom)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$('input:radio').change(
function(){
   //change iframe height here
}
);
```

Comment: Something like this?   $('input:radio').change('.my-div-class', function(){
   $(iframe).contents().find('body').html(''); // clear content of iframe
    console.debug();
    resizeFunction(iframe);
});

Comment: Did that code helped you? I dont think you can directly access the content of your iframe and resize accordingly. By far you can directly assign a height to it.

Comment: I haven't gotten it to work yet. I don't really know javascript. I'm more of a php developer. I think it has more to do with how I'm resizing the iframe than what causes it to resize. The problem is most likely with my code, not yours. Thanks!

Comment: Your question about binding the event to radio button is what my answer is for. But how to dynamically resize you iframe according to the content depends upon your code. It is possible though, read this blog: http://blog.holisticon.de/2012/02/domanenubergreifend-die-grose-eines-iframes-andern-cross-domain-iframe-resizing/

Comment: Thanks Rajiv! I marked your answer as the best answer since you did answer my initial question. I'll look over that site and see if I can't figure this thing out.

Comment: That link sheds some light on what I need, however I do have one additional question. My iframe id=responsive and my div class is .test. On the code from the link you provided it has var  iFrame = jQuery ( '# iframe' , parent.document.body);
    var  height = jQuery ( 'body' ) outer height (. true ); So I place my iframe id and class name accordingly or do I leave the var height as 'body'?